# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.msmq

Tags: wcf, msmq

I am trying to create a self-hosted service that listens to amessage queue, and sends an email when a message is put in the queue. However, I am getting the rather well known error

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.msmq for the
>   endpoint with binding NetMsmqBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http].

I have removed all the http stuff in the config file, an I know for a fact that MSMQ is working on my computer, as I have another MSMQ running just fine. The MailNotificationAgentQueue is also created.

Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netMsmqBinding>
            <binding exactlyOnce="false" deadLetterQueue="None" durable="True" maxRetryCycles="10" receiveRetryCount="10" useActiveDirectory="True" receiveErrorHandling="Fault">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" />
                </security>        
            </binding>
        </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MailNotificationAgentEndpointBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="netMsmqBinding" scheme="net.msmq" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="MailNotificationAgent.MailNotificationAgentService" behaviorConfiguration="MailNotificationAgentEndpointBehavior">

            <endpoint address="" binding="netMsmqBinding" name="MsmqEndpoint" contract="MailNotificationAgent.IMailNotificationAgentService" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.msmq://<MyComputerName>/private/MailNotificationAgentQueue" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks in advance!